# connecting to postgres using ODBC windows with gssencmode not working

Tags: postgresql, odbc, gssapi

connecting to postgres using ODBC windows with gssencmode not working

error : #gssencmode value "require" invalid when GSSAPI support is not complied in

Comment: Sounds like your ODBC driver is not compiled to support this.  Which does not surprise me at all, as Windows has its own Kerberos implementation which is only kind of compatible with GSS.